# Möchten and wollen explanation

Tags: word-choice, auxiliary-verb

1. *Wenn Sie rauchen **möchten**, müssen Sie nach draußen gehen.*

Oder soll ich schreiben …

2. *Wenn Sie rauchen **wollen**, müssen Sie nach draußen gehen.*

To me 1. looks correct but I just started German and there is a good chance I am wrong. From my understanding *möchten* would be used because it isn’t a “I WILL” kind of situation, it isn’t as strong as *wollen* and *wollen* is used when the person has more of their heart put into, correct? Please help me to unterstand these two.

By the way, I know that *möchten* comes from *mögen*, so that’ll keep ya from explaining that.

Comment: It doesn’t answer the question, but fewer words would usually suffice: _Bitte nur draußen rauchen!_

Answer (score 6):

*wollen* ist usually stronger than *möchten*. In this example I would therefore prefer *möchten*, so I would go with the first sentence.

*wollen* would be more appropriate when you may as well add *wirklich* or *unbedingt* without changing the meaning too much:

> Wenn Sie **wirklich** rauchen wollen, (dann) müssen Sie nach draußen gehen.
>
> Wenn Sie **unbedingt** rauchen wollen, (dann) müssen Sie nach draußen gehen.

which shifts the meaning from *want to* to *have to*. You may also say

> Wenn Sie **wirklich** rauchen **müssen**, (dann) müssen Sie nach draußen gehen.
>
> Wenn Sie **unbedingt** rauchen **müssen**, (dann) müssen Sie nach draußen gehen.

Which is even stronger (i.e. you are really addicted and can't help it).

However, despite this slight difference in meaning, in day-to-day usage, both *möchten* and *wollen* are used mostly interchangeably. Only be careful when making yourself the subject of the sentence. Then *wollen* might be perceived as too strong and impolite (say *Ich möchte gern…* instead of *Ich will…*).

Comment: Thank you for your help! That makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: +1 für den letzten Satz.
"Möchten" ist höflicher als "Wollen".

Comment: @josiah If that answers your question, could you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Ich möchte wirklich keinen Kuchen mehr. Ich möchte unbedingt mal nach Berlin.

Comment: @Robert Not quite sure what you want to say. You are using *möchten* in exactly the sense in which it can be replaced with *wollen* except for maybe that it sounds a little too harsh and *möchten* is a little more humble and polite. But I wrote that in my answer as well.

Comment: Just giving examples to show that "wirklich" and "unbedingt" can be used with either "möchten" or "wollen" in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

In English I typically think of möchten as having approximately the same politeness level as "would like" and wollen being similar to "want".